# Laravel additional parameters in custom local scopes suddenly not being passed properly

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Out of the blue suddenly my custom scopes in Laravel are no longer working. Somehow when used it's failing to separate additional parameters given from the `$query` parameter, clumping them into single array.

This results for instance a simple scope like the following failing because "Call to a member function whereNull() on array"

```
    // WHERE IS ACTIVE
    public function scopeWhereIsActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull('show_until')->where('is_old', false)
            ->orWhere('show_until', '>', now())->where('is_old', false)
            ->orderByDesc('created_at');
    }
```

And if I use a custom scope with additional parameters like the following, I get a missing arguments error (1 passed at least 2 expected). The thing however is that it worked perfectly just before, and I can't find any changes made that would affect this.

```
    /** WHERE HAS PRODUCT  
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  
     * @param  App\Models\Product $product
     * @param  boolean|false $return_with_loaded_products
     * @param  array $included_number_type_sums_array
     * @return void
     */
    public function scopeWhereHasProduct($query, $product, $return_with_loaded_products = false, $included_number_type_sums_array = null)
    {
        // dd('Order@scopeWherehasProduct parameters', $query, $product, $return_with_loaded_products , $included_number_type_sums_array);

        $query->whereHas('products', function($query) use ($product) {
            $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
        });

        if (isset($included_number_type_sums_array)) {
            foreach ($included_number_type_sums_array as $type) {
                $query->withSum(['products' => function($query) use($product) {
                    $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
                }], 'int_orders_products.number_' . $type);
            }
        }

        if ($return_with_loaded_products) {
            $query->with(['products' => function($query) use($product) {
                $query->where('product_id', $product->id);
            }]);
        }

        return $query;
    }
```

The `$parameters` parameter for the Laravel function calling the scope in `Illuminate/Database/Eloquent.Model.php` is a standard array, which I think should be correct, but the problem is that it's not being then split up across the separate parameter variables somehow.

```
    /**
     * Apply the given named scope if possible.
     *
     * @param  string  $scope
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function callNamedScope($scope, $parameters = [])
    {
        dd('halt',$parameters);
        return $this->{'scope'.ucfirst($scope)}($parameters);
    }
```

This returns for the first scope:

```
^ array:1 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1877 ▼
    #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#1864 ▶}
    #model: App\Models\Announcement {#1923 ▶}
    #eagerLoad: []
    #localMacros: []
    #onDelete: null
    #propertyPassthru: array:1 [▶]
    #passthru: array:21 [▶]
    #scopes: []
    #removedScopes: []
  }
]
```

I haven't touched anything 'deep' in the Laravel code that I know off, and rolling back isn't helping. My guess is that something deep in Laravel itself got wonked, but I really don't know where to look for these kind of issues. The laravel version is 9.15.00

Comment: its not spreading them because the spread operator isn't being used ... you must have altered the `callNamedScope` method

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix it though by upgrading Laravel at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could confirm what the problem was, apparently it could have been an altered `callNamedScope' function. I solved the issue by upgrading to the latest Laravel version (9.54.00).